# Tweepy to sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tweepy

I'm trying to use Twitter's Streaming API to save tweets to a database using sqlite3.  The problem is my database comes back empty.  I'm using DB Browser for SQLIte to check the schema and the table and columns are there but no values for any column.  Any thoughts?

```
#create sql table
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter_one5.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE tweets
    (coordinates integer,
    place text)''')
conn.commit()
conn.close()

# open connection
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter_one5.db')
c = conn.cursor()
```

Create a class to handle inserting tweet info into database:

```
class Tweet():

    # data from tweet
    def __init__(self, coordinates, place):
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.place = place

    # insert data from tweet into DB
    def insertTweet(self):
        c.execute("INSERT INTO tweets (coordinates, place) VALUES(?, ?)", 
        (self.coordinates, self.place))
        conn.commit()
```

Create a tweet listener using the Streaming API:

```
class listener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):

        tweet_data  = Tweet(status.coordinates, status.place)
        tweet_data.insertTweet()
        print('inserted')
```

Create instance of listener and filter for keywords:

```
l = listener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(track=['twitter'])
```

Comment: Just want to verify: does it print inserted at runtime? If not, you're just not storing anything.

Comment: Not many tweets have coordinates or place, and you seem to be assuming that all of them will. Have you checked that the tweets you are processing do include location data?