# How to get tweets to upload into an SQLite database using Python/Tweepy?

Tags: python, sqlite, twitter, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

Hi so I have some code that streams tweets from Twitter's API and performs sentiment analysis on them as a CSV file. What I want to do is for the tweets to upload into an SQLite database prior to performing the sentiment analysis. I've had a pretty good go at getting it work and just can't figure it out. I've used the documentation from https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html and looked at numerous Stack posts ( [tweepy stream to sqlite database - invalid synatx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434205/tweepy-stream-to-sqlite-database-invalid-synatx?noredirect=1&lq=1) , [Python tweepy writing to sqlite3 db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432187/python-tweepy-writing-to-sqlite3-db) , [tweepy stream to sqlite database - invalid synatx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434205/tweepy-stream-to-sqlite-database-invalid-synatx) , [Tweepy to sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750209/tweepy-to-sqlite3) ) but I still can't get it doing what I need it to do. I've also looked at tutorials here (https://tech.marksblogg.com/sqlite3-tutorial-and-guide.html) (https://recycledrobot.co.uk/words/?sqlite) and still can't get my INSERT statement right. The CREATE TABLE works and creates the SQLite file but I can't get my tweets to store into. I also only run the CREATE TABLE statement once then comment it out. Whole code is below. Any help much appreciated!

```
import csv
import re
import sys
import tweepy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from textblob import TextBlob
import sqlite3 as lite
# import models.py
global db
global cursor


class SentimentAnalysis:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tweets = [] # initialising empty list objects
        self.tweetText = []
        # self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)

    # Change access details below to point to own application
    def download_data(self):
        # authenticating
        consumerKey = '***'
        consumerSecret = '***'
        accessToken = '***'
        accessTokenSecret = '***'
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
        auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)

        # input for term to be searched and how many tweets to search
        searchTerm = input("Enter Keyword/Tag to search about: ")
        NoOfTerms = int(input("Enter how many tweets to search: "))

        # searching for tweets
        self.tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm, lang="en").items(NoOfTerms)

        # Open/create a file to append data to
        csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')

        # Use csv writer
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

        # creating variables to store info
        polarity = 0
        positive = 0
        wpositive = 0
        spositive = 0
        negative = 0
        wnegative = 0
        snegative = 0
        neutral = 0

        # iterating through tweets fetched
        for tweet in self.tweets:
            # Append to temp so that we can store in csv later. I use encode UTF-8
            self.tweetText.append(self.clean_tweet(tweet.text).encode('utf-8'))
            # print (tweet.text.translate(non_bmp_map))    #print tweet's text
            analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
            # print(analysis.sentiment)  # print tweet's polarity
            polarity += analysis.sentiment.polarity  # adding up polarities to find the average later

            if analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:  # adding reaction of how people are reacting to find average later
                neutral += 1
            elif 0 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0.3:
                wpositive += 1
            elif 0.3 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0.6:
                positive += 1
            elif 0.6 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 1:
                spositive += 1
            elif -0.3 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0:
                wnegative += 1
            elif -0.6 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= -0.3:
                negative += 1
            elif -1 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= -0.6:
                snegative += 1

        # Write to csv and close csv file
        csvWriter.writerow(self.tweetText)
        # csvFile.close()  # delete this for the insert SQL code bit

        con = lite.connect(r"C:\\Users\\Student User\\PycharmProjects\\DataScienceLabs\\tweets.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE tweets(created_at text, id_str text, text text)''')
        # commented out as models.py creates database

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweets(?, ?, ?)", (created_at,
                                                    id_str,
                                                    text))

        con.commit()

        # finding average of how people are reacting
        positive = self.percentage(positive, NoOfTerms)
        wpositive = self.percentage(wpositive, NoOfTerms)
        spositive = self.percentage(spositive, NoOfTerms)
        negative = self.percentage(negative, NoOfTerms)
        wnegative = self.percentage(wnegative, NoOfTerms)
        snegative = self.percentage(snegative, NoOfTerms)
        neutral = self.percentage(neutral, NoOfTerms)

        # finding average reaction
        polarity = polarity / NoOfTerms

        # printing out data
        print("How people are reacting on " + searchTerm + " by analyzing " + str(NoOfTerms) + " tweets.")
        print()
        print("General Report: ")

        if polarity == 0:
            print("Neutral")
        elif 0 < polarity <= 0.3:
            print("Weakly Positive")
        elif 0.3 < polarity <= 0.6:
            print("Positive")
        elif 0.6 < polarity <= 1:
            print("Strongly Positive")
        elif -0.3 < polarity <= 0:
            print("Weakly Negative")
        elif -0.6 < polarity <= -0.3:
            print("Negative")
        elif -1 < polarity <= -0.6:
            print("Strongly Negative")

        print()
        print("Detailed Report: ")
        print(str(positive) + "% people thought it was positive")
        print(str(wpositive) + "% people thought it was weakly positive")
        print(str(spositive) + "% people thought it was strongly positive")
        print(str(negative) + "% people thought it was negative")
        print(str(wnegative) + "% people thought it was weakly negative")
        print(str(snegative) + "% people thought it was strongly negative")
        print(str(neutral) + "% people thought it was neutral")

        self.plotPieChart(positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral, searchTerm,
                          NoOfTerms)

    def clean_tweet(self, tweet):
        # Remove links, special characters, etc., from tweet
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t]) | (\w +:\ / \ / \S +)", " ", tweet).split())

    # function to calculate percentage
    def percentage(self, part, whole):
        temp = 100 * float(part) / float(whole)
        return format(temp, '.2f')

    def plotPieChart(self, positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral, searchTerm, noOfSearchTerms):
        labels = ['Positive [' + str(positive) + '%]', 'Weakly Positive [' + str(wpositive) + '%]','Strongly Positive [' + str(spositive) + '%]', 'Neutral [' + str(neutral) + '%]',
                  'Negative [' + str(negative) + '%]', 'Weakly Negative [' + str(wnegative) + '%]', 'Strongly Negative [' + str(snegative) + '%]']
        sizes = [positive, wpositive, spositive, neutral, negative, wnegative, snegative]
        colors = ['yellowgreen','lightgreen','darkgreen', 'gold', 'red','lightsalmon','darkred']
        patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, startangle=90)
        plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="best")
        plt.title('How people are reacting on ' + searchTerm + ' by analyzing ' + str(noOfSearchTerms) + ' Tweets.')
        plt.axis('equal')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()

    # def plt_histogram


if __name__== "__main__":
    # db_init()
    sa = SentimentAnalysis()
    sa.download_data()
```

Comment: You're using the variables `created_at`, `id_str` and `text` in the INSERT statement but haven't set their values.

Comment: And be sure to check out [sqlite create table doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) to see how to use "IF NOT EXISTS" to solve the other problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what values I would set them too @jignatius? I just want them to be column headers in the table so don't understand what value they would have. @DinoCoderSaurus Do I put it in the table CREATE table statement to stop it having an effect once the table is created?